# App Android sem conexão a endereços IP válidos

Tags: java, android

Estou tendo um problema muito estranho com minha aplicação android, em certos casos minha aplicação não consegue resposta de endereços válidos de outros locais. Explicando minha aplicação, é um aplicativo de coleta de dados em campo, onde ela se conecta com o servidor do cliente para transferir as informações remotamente, via socket connection, o problema é que alguns clientes minha aplicação consegue se conectar e outros não, fiz diversos testes com endereços variados, alguns a aplicação consegue resposta e outros não. Segue codigo de verificação:

```
if (InetAddress.getByName(sys.getNr_ipexterno()).isReachable(3000)) {
    ipAcessivel = sys.getNr_ipexterno();
    Log.d("IP" , sys.getNr_ipexterno() + " Responde");
    try {
        Socket socket = new Socket(ipAcessivel, 5555);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        ipAcessivel = "";
    }
}
```

O problema é que o meu sistema não consegue nem fazer a validação do endereço, como esta na primeira linha deste código.

Comment: Poste o printStackTrace ;)

Comment: Mas o método " isReacable() " não lança exception.. ele não passa desse if, o try ali dentro é para ver se, após conseguir verificar se o ip do servidor remoto esta acessível, verificar se ele consegue conectar ao servidor socket..

Comment: Você adicionou permissão no manifest.xml de conexão externa?

Comment: Sim, o detalhe é que alguns IPs respondem e outros não, inclusive testei com IPs válidos do próprio google e me retorna false nesta validação :s

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922543/why-does-inetaddress-isreachable-return-false-when-i-can-ping-the-ip-address

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779367/problem-with-isreachable-in-inetaddress-class

Comment: Cara, esta quase hehe, parece que é mesmo esse método isReachable() que nem sempre retornar true.. agora tenho que ver só uma alternativa

Comment: http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4921816

Comment: Se você quiser testar se o site tá no ar ou dando resposta, pode disparar uma vez contra o site e ver a resposta do html...se der 200, deu boa ;)

Comment: na verdade eu tenho um servidor socket rodando em cada cliente, acho que vou apenas testar a conexão do socket e deixar de lado o ping... acho que já resolver meu problema.. só para esclarecer, eu tenho que fazer este teste, pois, o usuário pode sincronizar os dados tanto estando na rede local, quanto fora da empresa usando 3g..

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido, o problema esta no método isReachable(), ele não me retorna garantidamente se o destino esta acessível, então mudei a minha lógica para apenas validar a conexão diretamente com meu servidor socket, deste modo:

```
                ipAcessivel = sys.getNr_iplocal();
                try {
                    int timeoutMs = 2000;
                    SocketAddress sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress(ipAcessivel, 5555);
                    Socket sock = new Socket();

                    sock.connect(sockaddr, timeoutMs);

                    //Socket socket = new Socket(ipAcessivel, 5555);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    ipAcessivel = "";
                }
```